# Appium 1.6 1 with IOS 10 and Xcode 8.0 - unable to launch appium inspector

Tags: xcode8, appium-ios

I am trying to automate iOS iPAD native app. I have installed Appium 1.6.1 as per the instructions given git web site. However I am unable to launch the application and also appium inspector to locate/identify the objects in my native app.

I am trying to connect to realiPad device with iOS v9.3.5

Comment: You can check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/42950879/5221317

Answer (score 0):

With xcode 8.0 you cannot run your tests on ios 9 devices.Either you have to downgrade the xcode and appium or you have to run on ios 10 devices.